# Disable Auto-resize guest display using the CLI in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I'm doing some automations that required a very specific guest resolution, sometimes while moving the window around it might get resized by magnetic zones of the host OS.

I'm **wondering if there is some CLI command to disable *Auto-resize guest display*** so I can automatically disable the feature in every packer build.

I haven't been able to find it in VBoxManage at all.